# can not run smbclient from cronjob for remote file sharing

Tags: mysql, cross-platform, samba

i have a rancher server where I do MySQL dump and i need to send those dumped data in my NAS server so i created shell script for database dump and to backup in NAS server

```
#!/bin/bash
YEAR=`date +%Y`
MONTH=`date +%m`
DAY=`date +%-d`
mysqldump -hServerIP -uUsername -pPassword databasename>/home/rancher/backup.sql
smbclient //serverIp/path -U username -c 'cd /home/rancher; put backup.sql MySQLBackup/'$YEAR'/backup.sql'
```

if I execute above shell script manually then it works but when I try to execute using cronjob only mysqldump part work but smbclient part doesn't work.

For cronjob i am using 
*/2 * * * * exec `/bin/bash /home/rancher/backup.sh`

Comment: *doesn't work* is not much information for us to go on.  What happens when you run the `smbclient` part of your cron script directly from a shell? You can try  it with a tiny little file to get it working.

Comment: smblient part works and copy files in my NAS server while I directly run from shell

Comment: problem is i can not run smbclient using cron